# Binding datatable to datagrid does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, datagrid

I would like to bind a DataTable to a datagrid in c#

but it does not work

```
 DTable21 D21 = new DTable21();

            D21.initDataTB();

            dGrid.DataContext = D21.DataTB;



public void initDataTB() {

            DataTB.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
            DataTB.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
}
```

No columns appears - Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DTable21 D21 = new DTable21();
D21.initDataTB();
grid.DataContext = D21.DefaultView;



public void initDataTB()
{
     DataTB.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
     DataTB.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
}
```

In xaml file

```
<DataGrid Name="grid" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
```